# How to allow .appxbundle file extension on Azure WebApplication?

Tags: azure, uwp

A basic question, but I can not find how to do this.

I need to put a **.appxbundle** file hosted on a Azure WebApplication, but when I try to download, it

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

If, for example, I rename to .appxbundle.zip, then the file downloads normally.

Comment: These silent unfair downvotes are a bad thing here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I solved adding the staticContent tag on the Web.config file, under system.webServer, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".appinstaller" />
        <remove fileExtension=".appxbundle" />
        <remove fileExtension=".cer" />
        <remove fileExtension=".ps1" />
        <remove fileExtension=".psd1" />
        <remove fileExtension=".appx" />

        <mimeMap fileExtension=".appinstaller" mimeType="application/xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".appxbundle" mimeType="application/xml" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".cer" mimeType="application/x-x509-ca-cert" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".ps1" mimeType="text/plain" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".psd1" mimeType="text/plain" />         
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".appx" mimeType="application/vns.ms-appx" />    
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/africaapps/2013/06/07/how-to-serve-static-json-files-from-a-windows-azure-website/

Comment: do you need anything else to enable .cer files?

Comment: I also added the `<remove fileExtension=".cer" />` to prevent some error due to extension already be registered.